# what are the correct methods to Observe MutableLiveData <ArrayList<Objects>> ? Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I am working on a RecyclerView that retrieves some of the data from an Object, every time a new object is created that object will be added into SQLiteDatabase and then to my ViewModel MutableLiveData<ArrayList>. so my question is how can i set a method in my fragment that observes the changed array list of objects so that my recyclerview will automatically updated.

for MutableLiveData i have used the below method to Observe but its not working for ArrayList of objects in my case.

//this is an example

```
ViewModel.getChangedData().observe(requireActivity(),item->{
            textview.setText(item);
```

please help, i am a beginner in this.
i am using Java.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code of your viewmodel and also the fragment that you are observing it in

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Guys i have figured it out.. i needed to do this  candidates = myViewModel.getCandidates().getValue();

Answer (score 0):

Guys i have figured it out.. i needed to do this

```
candidates = myViewModel.getCandidates().getValue();
instead i was doing,  candidates = myViewModel.getCandidates();
```

`candidates` is ArrayList in this case